# How to use href and click listener togather?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of links each one of them has href attribute:

```
<a href="./page1.php" class="points">page 1</a>
<a href="./page2.php" class="points">page 2</a>
<a href="./page3.php" class="points">page 3</a>
<a href="./page4.php" class="points">page 4</a>
```

and I have a listener for the class "points" :

```
$(".points").live('click',function(){
    id = $(this).attr("id");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'points.php',
        data:{id:id},
        success: function()
        {

        },
        error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(XMLHttpRequest);
            alert(textStatus);
            alert(errorThrown);
            alert(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
        }
    });
});
```

the href is work but the click does not , when I remove the href attribute the click listener works perfectly.Is it possible for those two to work togather?

Comment: Did you try: `$(".points").live('click',function(e){ e.preventDefault();` as first line in your function?

Comment: Also, you might want to look into using `.on()` instead of `.live()`

Comment: FYI: `.live` has been deprecated for a long time and removed from the latest versions of jQuery. Use `.on` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Ajax & Href to work together

Try

```
  $(".points").live('click',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var id = $(this).attr("id");
  var url= $(this).attr("href");

   $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: 'points.php',
   data:{id:id},
    success: function()
    {
     //Do something before going to page
       window.location.href=url;

    },
    error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(XMLHttpRequest);
        alert(textStatus);
        alert(errorThrown);
        alert(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
    }
   });
   });
```

Comment: you need to `preventDefault()` to run this.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to cancel the default behavior, as the instant you navigate away, script will stop running.  You could consider waiting until the Ajax call finishes, then navigating via script:

```
$(".points").live('click',function(e){ // <--- Add e parameter

    e.preventDefault(); // <--- Add this

    id = $(this).attr("id");
    href = $(this).attr("href"); // Link we will navigate to when done
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'points.php',
        data:{id:id},
        success: function()
        {
           location.href = href; // Do the navigation now that we're done
        },
        error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(XMLHttpRequest);
            alert(textStatus);
            alert(errorThrown);
            alert(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I want them to work togather, if I add this line it will just run the javascript but the href will not work (I try it )

Comment: Yea there's no way to do that.  The instant you navigate away, script will stop running on that page.

Comment: @BaselShbeb - One possible solution is to wait until the Ajax call finishes, then navigate away.  I've updated my code (untested, hopefully it'll work)

Comment: The way to accomplish this would be to explicitly call a location.href navigation using the `href` attribute in the link tag in the success function of your AJAX post.  You will still need the `preventDefault` to enable the AJAX call to execute.  I will note however that this is completely contradictory to the purpose of AJAX.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$(".points").live('click',function(e){ //added e as function argument
    e.preventDefault(); //added preventDefault();
    var id = this.id; // changed here to this.id, and added var (so it will be a local variable)
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'points.php',
        data:{id:id},
        success: function()
        {

        },
        error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(XMLHttpRequest);
            alert(textStatus);
            alert(errorThrown);
            alert(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
        }
    });
});
```

- To read about [**preventDefault()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.preventDefault)
- Note that `As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers.`

Comment: +1 - I like the suggestion to use `this.id`.  On top of it, it might be worth mentioning that `id = this.id` creates a global variable OR overwrites a local one in the scope chain. This may be correct, but more likely an oversight in the OPs code.